# VBA code conflict

Tags: vba, excel

I know, I am asking an unusual question. But, please do help me.

I have a below code on Workbook that will take care of copy/paste data on sheets. It would allow me to paste data into the cells without changing format(past only values).

Basically, the code will use destination formatting. similar to "paste values". It would allow the user to paste data from any other format. So that format is consistent across sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vNewValues as Variant
    NewValues = Target
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Target = NewValues
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Along with above code, I also have another code on the sheet that will help me to clear the contents and code is linked to a button. So, when the button is pressed it will clear the contents of the sheet.

```
Private Sub ResetKey_Click()
If MsgBox("Content of the sheet will be deleted and cannot be restored", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("User").Range("E19:I3018").ClearContents
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Concern: I see a conflict between these codes. Because, when I click on the button I get the error that will point me to `Application.Undo` in the first code. I tried debugging the code but I was not able to get both to work. Please Suggest.

[image]

Comment: `ClearContents` triggers `Workbook_SheetChange`, and `Undo` cannot work because running a macro (like `ResetKey_Click`) clears the undo stack. Either don't trigger events from `ResetKey_Click` or revise your approach altogether. Excel specifically has "paste values only".

Comment: Your first block of code declares `vNewValues` but uses `NewValues`.  I'd suggest ticking `Require Variable Declaration` in the the **VBE Options ~ Editor** Tab (adds `Option Explicit` at the top of all new modules).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook , But how does it solve my current issue. I tried to do so and nothing changed with respect to my concern.

Comment: @GSerg, Please elaborate, can I replace Undo with any other functionalities so that I can use both the piece of codes.

Comment: It doesn't which is why I didn't add as an answer. It's just good coding practice - you won't inadvertently create new variables when you're meant to be referencing existing ones.  E.g. `lNewValue` is set to 10, elsewhere you use `NewValue` by mistake - the code executes, but uses the value of 0 rather than 10.

Comment: Wouldn't the code work if you just removed that line?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? please go into more detail than `take care of copy/paste data on sheets`, which does not describe the reason for your code. .... why do you feel that you need to use `undo` in your code? ... i am asking because i do not know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Nope, it wouldnt work if I remove the line `Undo`

Comment: @jsotola Basically, the code will use destination formatting. similar to "paste values". It would allow the user to paste data from any other format. So that format is consistent across sheets.

Comment: please update your question with the information in your comment. also include the description of data format that you are pasting (only the data format that does not paste correctly without using your code)

Comment: @jsotola Done, do you suggest any other way of retaining the format? or pasting only values on the sheet. So that I can avoid `Undo`

Comment: what is it that you are pasting into the worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Private Sub ResetKey_Click()
    If MsgBox("Content of the sheet will be deleted and cannot be restored", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Worksheets("User").Range("E19:I3018").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

That is, you have to suppress the Change event in other macros working on that sheet. Not elegant but doable.

To clarify what the first macro does: it saves the cell's content, undoes a user's paste or input, and then only fills in the value which was pasted, leaving the format intact. The problem with this approach is that the event handler does not return information on the action that triggered it - it could be a paste but clearing cells as well.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can only use .Undo to undo the last action in the worksheet not to undo vba actions and must be the first line in the macro. As explained in the documentation.[Application.Undo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-undo-method-excel). Quote below:

> This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before
>   running the   macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It
>   cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands.

Comment: It would be nice to include at least the relevant part(s) of that link. This answer otherwise loses half its value the day that link rots.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - You are absolutely right. I have updated accordingly.